# Linear combination of vectors in orthogonal set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

If an orthogonal set is linearly independent how can we get the linear combination of these vectors to form another vector that is in the orthogonal set? I thought linear independence meant you can't form another vector that is in the set based off of the vectors in a set.

The only thing that can equal $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_nv_n=0$ is where scalars $c_1,c_2,...,c_n$ are $0$, meaning no multiples of those vectors can form another vector.

Edit:

For example $S=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ where $v_1=[1,2,3]$, $v_2=[1,1,-1]$, $v_3=[5,-4,1]$ is an orthogonal subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Vectors in $S$ are non-zero so $S$ is linearly independent.

Let $u=[3,2,1]$, now we can write $u$ as a linear combination of the vectors in $S$.

$u=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3$

Using the equation $c_i=\frac{\text{dot product of } u \text{ and } v_i}{||v_i||^2}$ we can obtain scalars for $c$ where $u=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3$

Again how can you find this vector $u$ using the linear combination of the vectors in $S$ if $S$ is linearly independent? There should not be a vector $u$ that is a linear combination of the vectors in $S$ if $S$ is linearly independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of linear independence says you can't make 0 out of a linear combination. It says nothing about not being able to make any other vector out of linear combinations.

(1,0) and (0,1) are independent since you cannot write (0,0) = c(1,0) + d(0,1) without c=d=0. But you can write **every other vector** as a nontrivial linear combination of these. (2,3) = 2(1,0)+3(0,1) for example. Spend some time making sense of the definitions with some concrete examples like this one and it will make sense eventually.

If you call your orthogonal set $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$, you can trivially write any vector in your set as a linear combination (take all coefficients $0$ except the coefficient of $v_k$ which is $1$).

$v_k = 0\cdot v_1+0\cdot v_2+\dots+0\cdot v_{k-1}+1\cdot v_k+0\cdot v_{k+1}+\dots+0\cdot v_n$

This is true of any set, whether it is orthogonal or not.

Moreover, any vector in the span of $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ can be written as a linear combination of these vectors. This is again true of any set, whether orthogonal or not.

Comment: but if you make all coefficients except one 0 and we know that all vectors in the orthogonal set are non zero vectors, how does 0*v1+1*v2+...+0*vn=0, which proves that vectors in the set are linearly independent of one another? The concept of linear combination and linear independence being opposites as well as a orthogonal set being linearly independent yet getting the linear combination of the vectors in the set bringing about a new vector in the orthogonal set confuses me.

Comment: It is impossible to have independent vectors sum to $0$, but they can easily sum to one of the vectors in the set (in the way I wrote).

Comment: But if they cant sum to zero without the trivial coefficients being 0, doesnt that mean no linear combination of these vectors can form a new vector in the set?

Comment: What do you mean by "a new vector in the set"? You can't write $v_n$ as a combination of $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{n-1}$ if they are independent. But you can write $v_n$ as a combination of the whole set (in the way I wrote). Also, don't think of "linear combination" as opposite to "linear independence". "Linear dependence" is the opposite. A "linear combination" is a sum of scaled vectors which is used in the definitions of independence and dependence.

Comment: Im not sure i understand the difference between the two(v1,v2,vn-1 vs the whole set)

Comment: It usually helps to have some examples in the plane. The vectors (1,0) and (2,0) are dependent, since there is a linear combination of them -2(1,0) + 1(2,0) which equals (0,0). The vectors (1,0) and (0,1) are orthogonal, hence independent. That means there is no linear combination c(1,0)+d(0,1) which equals (0,0) unless c=0 and d=0.

Comment: by the "whole set" I meant v1,v2,..,vn (all n vectors), the first list is just the first n-1.

Comment: Edited the question to add the problem i am struggling with.

Comment: Okay your edit about the definition of linear independence helped clear things up, thank you.

Comment: Great, happy to help!